# Make fixed header's width the same size as container div

Tags: html, css

The `header` element is inside a `div` container. I set `header` as `fixed` . It causes 2 problems:

1. The width of `header` overflows the width of the `div` element. It should match the `div`.
2. The other elements `nav` and `article` are not visible when I make `header` as fixed.

This is how it appears now:
[image: output]

This is how I want it to appear:
[image: Image2]

here's my code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
header{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   right:0px;
}
header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright © W3Schools.com</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have a fixed header with a non-fixed height, so can you give the header a fixed height? ... Else you need a different solution, if you want the header to stay and the content visible and scrollable ... so which way to go?

Comment: I want both ; the header to be fixed and content (article) to be visible and scrollable if its large content.

Comment: And what are you saying ? Do I have to fix the height of header

Comment: Yes, as the other content needs to be pushed down the same height as the header, and if that height is unknown, it will overlap, unless you give it a value way higher "just in case"

Comment: But there is another way, having scrollable content and a fixed non-fixed height header, using `flexbox`. Is such solution an option for you or you need to support older browsers?

Comment: Setting the header height doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'll try using flexbox

Comment: No, just setting header height won't, you need to push content down too, i.e. give the container a padding or margin top the same value as the height on the header

Comment: I can post an answer with `flexbox` if you will accept that?

Comment: setting margins work . But without using flexbox is it the only way ?

Comment: When you give an element position fixed or absolute, it is taken out of flow and the other elements will behave like the positioned element isn't there, and that's why it overlaps and need, in this case, fixed heights.

Comment: Ok! now i understand .thanks

Comment: With `flexbox` you can get around that by both have a non-fixed header and a scrollable, visible content, and I recommend such, as fixed/absolute positioning will often come short when making responsive web sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me result you wanted:

```
header {
/* Everything else is same as your code*/
position: relative;
}
header,footer {
/* Everything else is same as your code*/
padding: 1em 0;
}
```

1. You set div width 100%, and header width 100% of its parent, and then set padding left and right of 1em (padding: 1em -> its padding from all 4 sides, padding:1em 0 -> top&bottom 1em, left&right 0).
2. why did you set fixed? Do you need header to be sticky to top?

> ```
> div.container {
>   width: 100%;
>   border: 1px solid gray;
> }
> header{
>   position:fixed;
>   width:100%;
> }
> header, footer {
>   /*padding: 1em 0;*/
>   color: white;
>   background-color: black;
>   clear: left;
>   text-align: center;
> }
> header h1 {
>   line-height: 2em;
>   font-size: 2em;
> }
> nav {
>   float: left;
>   max-width: 160px;
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 1em;
>   margin-top: 6em;
> }
> nav ul {
>   list-style-type: none;
>   padding: 0;
> }
> nav ul a {
>   text-decoration: none;
> }
> article {
>   margin-left: 170px;
>   border-left: 1px solid gray;
>   padding: 1em;
>   overflow: hidden;
>   margin-top: 6em;
> }
> ```

Comment: But i want header to be fixed and other elements to be visible

Comment: Yes i want header stick  to top even if window is scrolling

Comment: @Mitali can you try this. I have edited my answer. Tryed not to touch html, only css.

Comment: @Mitali Great! Than you can vote and accept my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing just put the container div before article. And if you want change the container width with min-width:100% . But if you need the article full window size. height:100vh; just need to add on your .article class which is already added by me. just run it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    min-width: 100%;
    
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
header{
   postion:fixed;
   width:100%;
   right:0px;
}
header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
     height:100vh; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
   <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
 
<div class="container">
<article>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in  
 the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million     
 inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for  
  two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who 
  named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright © W3Schools.com</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-top` (in my example 100px) to the first non-fixed element in the content to create the space for the fixed header stuff, plus add `html, body {margin: 0; }` to reset the default margins which affect the width of your non-fixed content.

And also use `box-sizing: border-box;` for all elements to include the borders in the percentage widths. (see snippet)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body,
    html {
      margin: 0;
    }
    div.container {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    header {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      right: 0px;
    }
    header,
    footer {
      padding: 1em;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      clear: left;
      text-align: center;
    }
    nav {
      float: left;
      max-width: 160px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1em;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    article {
      margin-left: 170px;
      border-left: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 1em;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header>
      <h1>City Gallery</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">London</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Paris</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <h1>London</h1>
      <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
    </article>

    <footer>Copyright © W3Schools.com</footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works .Thanks ! But can i have a much optimized way by not calculating margin-top

Comment: It only depends on the height of that fixed part at the top. Usually that's something you know (for example a header with a background image, with the text inside it), so you simply take that height as margin-top for the non-fixed content. (BTW: float and clear have no effect whatsoever in a fixed element - you got a `clear: both` in your header...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p><b>Tip:</b> To see the effect, try to resize the window if the scrollbar is not available.</p>

    <p><b>Tip:</b> Tapping the screen will hide and show the header/footer IF the scrollbar is available. The effect varies depending on where you are on the page.</p>

    <p>Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..Some text to enable scrolling..</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```